# monotouch Ad Hoc Distribution for iPad

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, code-signing, ad-hoc-distribution

I was attempting to deploy my ipad app using the monotouch enterprise licence.
I follow the steps here.

http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Building_for_Distribution

and I did not see the   "iPhone Bundle Signing" 
 [image]

I did part 1

Got stuck on part 2

**EDIT**

dont forget to follow these steps too

http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

run the assistant for every new app you do. download cert and double check your 'bundle and signing' to make sure monotouch recognizes your provisioning profile

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979

Comment: Awesome screenshot :-) Are you aware that with SHIFT+CMD+3 you can take a snapshot of the whole screen and with SHIFT+CMD+4 select which part of the screen to capture? It will be saved to the desktop. Just a hint.

Comment: awesome tip, I love the SHIFT+CMD+4 trick  thanks Krumelur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your main (.exe) project options (i.e. not the solution options) and you should see it.